# compare quantity and search in array values

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have a conditional logic when user inputs a quantity there are predefined pricing for all quantities if qty is 200 price will be $4 if quantity is 400 price will be $4.8 so if user puts 150 as quantity it will check which is the value matched so it will get price which is matched within available quantity like user inputs 150 quantity so it lies in 200 condition so price wil be given which is defined for 200 quantity

available example condition on backend

```
 [wholesalePrices] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 10
                [price] => 9.99
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 25
                [price] => 8
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 50
                [price] => 6
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [quantity] => 100
                [price] => 4
            )
```

I tried using this but this doesn't work for me

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
   <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Costing" readonly />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show Cost" /> 
</form>

$data['wholesalePrices'] = 
    array(
      array('quantity' => 10, 'price' => 9.99),
      array('quantity' => 25, 'price' => 8),
      array('quantity' => 50, 'price' => 6),
      array('quantity' => 100, 'price' => 4)
    );

$qty = $_POST['quantity'];

if(in_array($qty , $data['wholesalePrices'])) {
    echo "price exist";
} else {
    echo "Not Matched";
}
```

my english is not so good so unable to explain properly please let me know if any more explanation would be required I hope you guys will help me out with this

Comment: You should check for ranges. You are checking just if the input value is in the array. For example, if the user type a quantity of 60, there is no match as 60 is not in the array. There is 50, there is 100, but all the intermediate values are not in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
$qty = $_POST['quantity'];

$matched=false;
foreach ($data['wholesalePrices'] as $row)
  if($row['quantity']==$qty) {
    $matched=true;
    break;
  }

if($matched) {
    echo "price exist";
} else {
    echo "Not Matched";
}
```

The necessity of the `foreach` loop also shows, that the structure of your data is not optimal.

**EDIT**

The question has been edited to not look for an exact match, but a range match - it is still not clear, so I'll assume the meaning is

- quantity 1-10: price 9.99
- quantity 11-25: price 8
- quantity 26-50: price 6
- quantity 51-100: price 4

This would give

```
$qty = $_POST['quantity'];
//Input sanitization missing: Must be integer >=1

$price=0;
foreach ($data['wholesalePrices'] as $row)
  if($row['quantity']>=$qty) {
     $price=$row['price'];
     break;
  }

if($price>0) {
    echo "price exist";
} else {
    echo "Not Matched";
}
```

Comment: not working if I am entreing quantity as 35 it is showing not matched it sould show me price of this array values 'quantity' => 50, 'price' => 6, as quantity is 35 so it;s in the range of 50 qunaityt

Comment: This is not what your question said - then you wanted an exact match. I'll adapt the answer.